# Get all notes(annotation) for case using ALEXACRM

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to get notes(annotation) for specific case(incident).
Here is my code:

```
$incidentid= '49243f9c-548e-e711-80c6-000c2983dc59';


$clientOptions  = include( 'config.php' );
$clientSettings = new Settings( $clientOptions );
$client         = new Client( $clientSettings );
$metadata       = MetadataCollection::instance( $client );

    /* $incident = $client->entity( 'incident', $contactKeyvv); */
   $contactKey2 = new \AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\Entity\EntityReference("incident");
    $contactKey2->__set("ID",$incidentid );

$notes = $client->entity('annotation', $contactKey2);
$isRetrievedByEmail = false;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($notes);
exit;
```

But I am not able to get these details using [ALEXACRM](https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit). What am I doing wrong ?

Also tried something similar to get cases(incident) for specific contact. but no luck. Here is code:

```
$contactKey = new \AlexaCRM\CRMToolkit\KeyAttributes();
$contactKey->add( 'customerid','5e61e646-8c8c-e711-80c6-000c2983dc59' );
$contactKey->add( 'customeridtype',2);

$contact_cases = $client->entity( 'incident', $contactKey);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($contact_cases);exit;
```

If anyone who has tried this, please help me

Comment: which version of crm ? retag is due. also, define "not able to" and "no luck": what's the result ? an error ? a hard drive format ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer from george GITHUB AlexaCRM.

```
    $xml='<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="annotation">
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <attribute name="notetext" />
    <attribute name="filename" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="annotationid" />
    <order attribute="subject" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="incident" from="incidentid" to="objectid" alias="ab">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="incidentid" operator="eq" uiname="abcdefg" uitype="incident" value="{'.$incidentid.'}" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>';

$clientOptions  = include( 'config.php' );
$clientSettings = new Settings( $clientOptions );
$client         = new Client( $clientSettings );
$metadata       = MetadataCollection::instance( $client );

$incident = $client->entity( 'incident', $incidentid);
if($incident->exists)
{
$notes = $client->retrieveMultiple($xml,$allPages = true, $pagingCookie = null, $limitCount = null, $pageNumber = null, $simpleMode = true );


$abc=array();
foreach ($notes->Entities as $note) {


    $abc2['subject']=$note->subject;
    $abc2['notetext']=$note->notetext;

    $abc2['annotationid']=$note->annotationid;
    $abc2['date_time']=$note->createdon->FormattedValue;
    $abc2['date_time_YMD']=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$note->createdon->Value);

    $abc[]=$abc2;


}
```